# Lotus Notes/Domino - How to get 'Content-Range' in Angular app

Tags: angular, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have created an Angular app and I am using HttpClient to get data from a IBM/Notes Domino server. I'm using Domino Data Services to access data in a database with a URL like this `/{database}/api/data/collections/name/{viewname}`.
The data comes back from the server just fine, I can see this using Chrome DevTools ' Network tab.

In the response from the server, I can see the `Content-Range` header but in my Angular app I cannot access it!

In the Angular app I am using this to observe the response from the server

```js
this.httpClient.get<any>('/{database}/api/data/collections/name/{viewname}', {observe: 'response'})
    .subscribe(
        resp => {
        console.log(resp);
        }
    );
```

In the console, I can see this for the headers: `headers: Map(3) {"content-type" => Array(1), "cache-control" => Array(1), "content-length" => Array(1)}`

I've added `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` in the custom headers in the Domino Web Site Rule with a value `Content-Range`.

Does anyone know how I can get to the `Content-Range` header in Angular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So with the help of the others I have the answer!

To help others here is the solution you need to follow to get it working on the Domino Server.

In the Domino Director, go to Web -> Internet Sites. In the Web Site Rule document **Rule (headers):** enter the following in the `Custom headers` fields:

[image]
Then in the Notes.ini file for the server you need the following line:

```
HTTPAdditionalRespHeader=HTTPAdditionalRespHeader=Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
```

Restart the Domino Server and hey presto it works!!

Comment: This answer assumes you are configuring CORS with a web site rule.  As of Domino 10.0.1 FP2, it is safer to use the new CORS filter.  For example, the CORS filter let's you configure access by origin.  In other words, you can allow a CORS request only from your Angular application.  A web site rule is the same for all origins.   Here's a link to the CORS filter documentation:  https://help.hcltechsw.com/domino/10.0.1/conf_cors.html

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have not added Content-range to the exposed headers on the server-side.

Maybe you can try this: 
`[EnableCors("http://localhost:3000", "", "", exposedHeaders: "Content-Range")]`

Comment: The problem is either in Angular getting the header or the IBM/Lotus Domino server not exposing the header. I'm thinking it's the Domino Server not exposing the header... don't know why though!

Comment: Have you used the rule `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: 'Content-range'` as one of the headers?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your backend to return HTTP header, `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` with the value of `Content-Range`. I.e., in full: `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Range`.

Then in Angular, you can retrieve the headers by doing a `.headers.get()`:

E.g.

```js
this.httpClient.get<any>('/{database}/api/data/collections/name/{viewname}', {observe: 'response'})
    .subscribe(
        resp => {
           console.log(resp);
           console.log(resp.headers.get('Content-Range'));
        }
    );
```